# Oracle SQL - Show percentage of two columns in new column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that is showing the volume per week of Pass / Fails for a test as two separate columns. I want to add a third column, that shows the percentage of fails - (1/(Failed+Passed))*Failed.

```
SELECT to_char(DATE,'YYYY'), to_char(DATE,'WW'), 
  SUM(case WHEN Result = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) Failed, 
  SUM(case WHEN Result = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) Passed
FROM Result_table
GROUP BY to_char(DATE,'YYYY'), to_char(DATE,'WW')
ORDER BY to_char(DATE,'YYYY'), to_char(DATE,'WW');
```

I believe I have to use the above as a sub query (so that Failed and Passed are already defined), however, I keep getting errors - so I am not sure if that is the right approach.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: How have you tried to use it in  subquery, and what errors did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this as a subquery you need to move the `order by` to the outer query, which means you need the year and week columns so be aliased:

```
SELECT year_num, week_num, failed, passed,
  100 * failed / (failed + passed) as failed_percent
FROM (
  SELECT to_char(DATE,'YYYY') as year_num,
    to_char(DATE,'WW') as week_num, 
    SUM(case WHEN Result = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as failed, 
    SUM(case WHEN Result = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) as passed
  FROM Result_table
  GROUP BY to_char(DATE,'YYYY'), to_char(DATE,'WW')
)
ORDER BY year_num, week_num;
```

Comment: Perfect! Not only does it work, you also identified exactly what I had been doing wrong (without even seeing what I had attempted).